# Почему Паралимпиада, но Параолимпийские игры?

Tags: морфология

Известно ли кому-либо из коллег, как произошла трансформация слов "паралимпиада - параолимпийский"? Грамота.ру в основном сообщает:"Искомое слово отсутствует".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это слово (*параолимпийский? паралимпийский?*) для русского языка по-прежнему относительно экзотическое, его нет в большинстве известных словарей - даже в словарях иностранных слов. Единственный словарь, где оно обнаруживается, это Орфографический, и то лишь в его электронной версии. Так вот, слово это выглядит в словаре - внимание! - как **параолимпийский**. Никаких других вариантов написания словарь не приводит.
Казалось бы, это логично. Ведь речь в данном случае идет о сложном слове, состоящем из двух частей: известном нам прилагательном "олимпийский" и приставки "пара-" (от греческого para - возле, около, при). Первая часть, пара-, указывает в сложных словах на то, что нечто находится рядом, около. Или же на отклонение от чего-либо (*паранормальный, парамагнитный*).
**Параолимпийские игры** - это спортивные состязания, те же олимпийские игры, но для инвалидов, людей с ограниченными возможностями. Проводятся по традиции следом за Олимпийскими играми, с некоторых пор даже в тех же городах. Параолимпийский: просто и ясно.

И тем не менее, в русском языке закрепилось написание "**паралимпийский**". Повторю, закрепилось пока не в словарях, а в речевой практике. Могу лишь предположить, что произошло это из-за не слишком удобного сочетания АО (парАОлимпийские), которое произносится как АА. Сработал принцип языковой экономии: вместо "параолимпийский" появилось слово "паралимпийский".
Кроме того, сказалось влияние английского языка, где "параолимпийские игры" выглядят сейчас как "paralympic games". Но, если посмотреть, каким это слово было в английском языке раньше, мы убедимся в том, что и там оно прошло похожий путь: от parAOlympic до parАlympic. А поскольку Паралимпийские игры, как и Олимпийские, - событие международное, понятно желание сделать терминологию в этой сфере универсальной. Раз международный комитет по организации подобных состязаний называется Paralympic, то и в русском языке должен быть Паралимпийским.
Есть одно "но"… При произнесении слова "паралимпийский" возникают нежелательные ассоциации со словом "паралич", и эти ассоциации настолько сильны, что многие задают вопрос: а не от этого ли слова произошло название олимпийских игр для инвалидов?
Подробный ответ на этот вопрос дан выше: нет, не от этого.

Подобную реакцию стоило в свое время учесть тем, кто сокращал слово *параолимпийский* и приводил его в соответствие с международной терминологией. Всё-таки в нем "олимпийская" часть просматривалась куда яснее - и никаких вопросов не возникало!
Боюсь, с сомнениями и опасениями мы опоздали. Игры уже **паралимпийские**. Такими, видимо, и останутся, а словарям придется лишь зафиксировать существующую норму.

И Грамота.ру дает слово **Паралимпиада** в Словаре имен собственных *с прописной буквы*.

Comment: Почему-то это объяснение через языковой экономии не очень срабатывает на сохранении "ориентира" вместо известного "я вижу аринтир".

Answer (score 3):

Друзья мои, а при чём тут русский? слово-то целиком из греколатинского. Я не самый большой и даже не знаток, но отчасти владею, в силу профессии, медицинской терминологией. Есть в греческом приставки ПАРА- и ПАР-. Насколько я понимаю, слово должно писаться парАОлимпиада, на худой конец, парОлимпиада. То , что нам предлагают, безграмотно. Посудите сами, если я вместо параОссальный (дословно перевожу"околокостный") буду писать (следуя логике парАлимпиады) параССАЛЬНЫЙ?

Answer (score 1):

Мне кажется, все гораздо проще.
"Паралимпиада" вынужденно закрепилось в словарях под давлением депутатов.
Я помню момент, когда был Думой принят какой-то документ, где было прописано именно паралимпиада и паралимпийские. Что уж там у них заклинило - не берусь сказать. 
Несмотря на возмущение "всей прогрессивной общественности", включая Лопатина, пришлось стерпеть.

~~~

Вопрос № 259386, Вопрос № 259167, Вопрос № 258439

Здравствуйте!
Интересует слово "ПАРАОЛИМПИЙСКИЙ". Этимология, а также современное написание. В печатном издании я встретила употребление "ПАРАЛИМПИЙСКИЙ". Правильно ли это?
С уважением, Наталья
abazur
Ответ справочной службы русского языка

Федеральным законом от 9 ноября 2009 г. № 253-ФЗ «О внесении изменений в отдельные законодательные акты Российской Федерации» (принят Государственной Думой 21 октября 2009 года, одобрен Советом Федерации 30 октября 2009 года) установлено единообразное использование в законодательстве Российской Федерации слов паралимпийский и сурдлимпийский, а также образованных на их основе словосочетаний: Паралимпийский комитет России, Паралимпийские игры и др.

Словарями русского языка (см., например: Русский орфографический словарь РАН / под ред. В. В. Лопатина. М., 2005) зафиксировано написание Параолимпийские игры, Параолимпиада. «Казалось бы, это логично, – писала Марина Королёва. – Ведь речь в данном случае идет о сложном слове, состоящем из двух частей: известном нам прилагательном "олимпийский" и "пара-" (от греческого para - возле, около, при). Первая часть, пара-, указывает в сложных словах на то, что нечто находится рядом, около. Или же на отклонение от чего-либо (паранормальный, парамагнитный). Параолимпийские игры – это спортивные состязания, те же Олимпийские игры, но для инвалидов, людей с ограниченными возможностями. Проводятся по традиции следом за Олимпийскими играми, с некоторых пор даже в тех же городах. Пара-олимпийский: просто и ясно». О первых случаях появления в официальных документах варианта Паралимпийские игры В. В. Лопатин, ответственный редактор «Русского орфографического словаря», председатель Орфографической комиссии РАН, говорил так: «У нас появилась Лимпиада».

И всё же официальными документами (теперь уже окончательно) установлено написание Паралимпийские игры (ср. англ. Paralympic Games, фр. Jeux Paralympiques, исп. Juegos Paralímpicos). Вот справка Государственно-правового управления к Федеральному закону от 9 ноября 2009 г. № 253-ФЗ: «В законах и подзаконных актах, принятых до вступления в силу Федерального закона от 4 декабря 2007 года № 329-ФЗ "О физической культуре и спорте в Российской Федерации", в написании этих слов использовалась буква "о", а именно: "параолимпийский" и "сурдоолимпийский". В названном Федеральном законе написание указанных слов приведено в соответствие с правилами, установленными международными спортивными организациями, что потребовало внесения необходимых изменений в ряд законодательных актов».

([gramota.ru](http://gramota.ru))

Comment: Набираю в яндексе - параолимпийский. Ответ: в запросе была исправлена опечатка - паралимпийский. И корень слова - лимпий?

Comment: Ну да.  )))
Новая фишка у нас теперь. "Нечленимое заимсвование" называется. капк с Беларусью.

Comment: Ну не совсем нечленимое. Русский суффикс и окончание все-таки есть. Давайте еще раз , пожалуйста. Морфемный состав  - пара+лимпий+ск+ий или паралимпий+ск+ий (коли "нечленимое")? Способ образования -  приставочный олимпийский+ приставка "пара" (и стяжение гласных) или суффиксальный паралимпий+ск (ий)? Как бы Вы зафиксировали в соответствующих словарях?

Comment: @Ларф, нечленимым заимствованием вынуждено объявили слово "паралимпиада". Флексия не в счет, это уже следствие преразложения. И якобы уже потом, на русской почве появились образования типа "паралимпийкий"  с присущими русскому афифксами.
Но при этом разложение внитри корня по правилам русского невозможно. Никакого делания на "пара" и "лимпийский", только целиком. Аналогично и с "сурдлимпиадой"

Comment: Вся эта история - влияние английского, где обожают всякие сочетания морфологически несочетаемого по типу "Википедия" или "Ирангейт". О классическом примере автобуса - "bus" (по сути - всего лишь латинском окончании родительно мнеожественного) я уж не говорю.

Comment: Понятно. Спасибо.

Answer (score 1):

Правильно говорить Паралимпиада и Паралимпийские игры. Приставочный способ: олимпийский + приставка "пара" (и стяжение гласных). Что вам не нравится? Это, кстати, и версия орг.комитета Игр в Сочи, по крайней мере, волонтёрам так на тренинге объяснили: произносить параолимпийский сложно, поэтому букву "о" убрали.

---

Кстати есть разница между Паралимпийскими (Олимпийскими) Играми и Паралимпиадой (Олимпиадой). Паралимпиада (как и Олимпиада) это культурное движение, процесс. Это и процесс тренировок, подготовки спортсменов, и пропаганда здорового образа жизни, ценностей Паралимпийского движения. А Игры (с заглавной буквы) это собственно сами состязания, проводимые раз в 4 года, во время и после которых спортсмены именуются атлетами.

Comment: >>Что вам не нравится?
  
Всё. Нет в русском ни такой приставки, ни такого корня. А что Вам не нравится в этом общеизвестном факте?
Еще не нравится, что "оргкомитет в Сочи" стал для кого-то авторитетным органом и по части грамматики (ну или морфологии) русского языка.

Answer (score 1):

Словари дают параОлимпийские и параОлимпиада. А для лингвистов и грамотных людей главный источник - это словари. Мы можем пока говорить только о тенденции в языке. Возможно, через несколько лет слово "паралимпийские" будет закреплено в словарях. Думаю, здесь обычное фонетическое явление - стяжение гласных. Язык пытается избавится от зияния. И если говорить о морфемном разборе и опираться на этимологию, то здесь тоже обычное наложение (сравни: военачальник, "н" входит и в первый корень, и во второй. А если вернуться к первому вопросу, то, думаю, всё связано с ударением: в слове ПАРАОЛИМПИАДА сочетание АО - это 3 и 4 предударные слоги, а в слове ПАРАОЛИМПИЙСКИЙ - 2 и 3, поэтому оно в первом слове произносится более бегло. И поэтому два одинаковых звука стягиваются в один.

Comment: А Вы какими словарями руководствуетесь?
Наверняка все были изданы до решения изменить написания.
Рассуждений о морфемном составе и стяжении не понял. 
"Сурдлимпийский" - это уже никаким стяжением не объяснишь. Просто закрепили по образу и подобию английского.

Answer (score 1):

По моему мнению в олимпийском комитете просто допустили ошибку из-за обычной неграмотности, либо же опечатку. И все принялись бездумно копировать это написание и произношение. По мне так - ничего удобного нет в произношении "паралимпийский", действительно паралич какой-то. А произношение "параолимпийский" абсолютно не напрягает, так как понятно что там и к чему: пара - около (тоже что и параномальный), олимпийский - тут все ясно. А вот сурдлимпийский - так это вообще нонсенс. Кому легче произносить "сурдлимпийский" с жутким стечением согласных РДЛ??? Куда дели буквы о, да хотя бы одну бы оставили, и списали бы все на наложение и то легче было бы произносить.

Answer (score 1):

"Паралимпиада" говорить безграмотно: нет такой горы "Лимп", есть "Олимп". Если в английском языке отрывать букву от корня - обычная практика, то не надо ее переносить на русский язык.

Answer (score 0):

Ссылаются на английский язык. Нашли авторитетов для русского языка?!
Как не вспомнить классику - "что скажет княгиня Марья Алексеевна". Так и продолжаем падать ниц перед забугорными "специалистами"

Теперь можно говорить, что у нас проходят "ЛИМПИЙСКИЕ" игры. Бред какой, то!

А депутатам надо ввести аттестацию на знание "великого и могучего". И гнать поганой метлой за отсутствие этих знаний.

А по поводу аргумента "сложно произносить" - закусывать надо и язык не будет заплетаться.

Comment: В чем-то вы правы, но хотелось бы более спокойного изложения. И желательно - ближе к теме.

Answer (score 0):

Да полно терминов, которые пишутся пара+о. Например, параовариальная киста, параорбитальная часть лица и т.д.

Comment: Как произошла трансформация? Таков вопрос был.

Comment: У вас есть предположения, как в слове *паралимпийский* появилась буква *о*?